# How can I check whether I'm in the topmost frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent

I have a function in JavaScript which is included in the main HTML document and all embedded `iframes`. The function should operate in the main document. So I tried:

```
function f() {
    if (parent === null) {
        ...do the real work here...
    } else {
        parent.f(); // Call parent
    }
}
```

That doesn't work. Apparently, `parent` is never `null` or `undefined`. Currently, I use `window == parent` which works but I'm uneasy. Is that correct? Why? How compatible is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `window==top`? Not tested with iframes, but I noticed that Google use that on gmail.

Comment: And I guess `top.f()` to call the topmost parent :-) Thanks, I completely missed `top`.